# Try/Catch Block - Exiting from try code

Tags: c#, try-catch, request.querystring

I have this C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data;

public partial class UpdateArticle : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public string ArticleTitle, ArticleBody, PostDate;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string ArticleId;
        try
        { ArticleId = Request.QueryString["ArticleId"].ToString();
            string dpath = Server.MapPath(@"App_Data") + "/MySite.mdb";
            string connectionstring = @"Data source='" + dpath + "';Provider='Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0';";
            string q = string.Format("select *  from tblArticles where ArticleId={0}", ArticleId);
            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionstring);
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(q, con);
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "tbl");
            con.Close();
            ArticleTitle = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ArticleTitle"].ToString();
            ArticleBody = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ArticleBody"].ToString();
            PostDate = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["PostDate"].ToString();


        }
        catch
        { }
        string NewArticleTitle, NewArticleDate, NewArticleBody, ArticleId1;  
        try
        {

                NewArticleTitle = Request.Form["ArticleTitle"].ToString();
                NewArticleDate = Request.Form["ArticleDate"].ToString();
                NewArticleBody = Request.Form["ArticleBody"].ToString();
                ArticleId1 = Request.QueryString["ArticleId"].ToString();
                string dpath = Server.MapPath(@"App_Data") + "/MySite.mdb";
                string connectionstring = @"Data source='" + dpath + "';Provider='Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0';";
                OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionstring);
                string QuaryString = string.Format("insert into tblArticles(ArticleTitle, ArticleBody, PostDate) values ('{0}','{1}','{2}') where ArticleId='{3}'", NewArticleTitle, NewArticleBody, NewArticleDate, ArticleId1);
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(QuaryString, con);
                OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds, "tbl");
                con.Close();
            }
            catch { }
       // Response.Redirect("ArticlesTable.aspx");

}}
```

The problem in my code is that when it comes to this line :

```
ArticleId1 = Request.QueryString["ArticleId"].ToString();
```

It exits from the try block.  A few lines above I wrote this code :

```
ArticleId = Request.QueryString["ArticleId"].ToString();
```

And it works just fine. So why is the lower line not working?
When I debug it in the first time: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esh4j.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfKXL.png
after submiting the form in the ASPX page: 
this is the aspx code:

```
<b>
כותרת המאמר :<br /></b><input id="Text1" type="text" name="ArticleTitle" value="<%=ArticleTitle %>"/><p></p>
<b>

תאריך פרסום: <br /></b><input id="Text2" type="text" name="ArticleDate" value="<%=PostDate %>"/><p></p>

<b>

תוכן המאמר: <br /></b> <textarea rows="10" cols="60"  name="ArticleBody"><%=ArticleBody %></textarea>
<br />
<input id="Reset1" type="reset" value="נקה" />
<input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="שלח כתבה!" />
</form>
<p></p><p></p>

<a href="Default.aspx">חזור לדף הבית</a>
```

And after the submit (The var not getting the Id value!) [image]

Comment: Catch the exception and display the exception information.

Comment: [MSDN using Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02(v=vs.110).aspx) -- `OleDbCommand` and `OleDbConnection` both implement `IDisposable`.

Comment: You need to step through your code and see what is happening

Comment: What is the reason of double accessing to `Request.QueryString["ArticleId"]`? Why dont you use `ArticleId`  to assign `ArticleId1`, if `ArticleId` is successfully initialized?

Comment: Try catching the exception like this:  `catch (Exception exc) { throw(exc); }

Comment: Are you sure that the first part completed successfully? How do you know that that exact line is the problem?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski When someone suggests a bad edit and your "improve" of that edit is just undoing everything they did, you shouldn't mark it as helpful, you should mark it as not helpful...

Comment: May be the Server.MapPath... ?

Comment: Wow I hope that code is not going into a company's application.  You should use using or at least close the connections on finally.  Also, catching exceptions without handling them is a great way to miss errors.  Are you sure that is the line that is generating the error?

Comment: Oh, and since nobody's mentioned it, you shouldn't be concatenating strings to create SQL queries; it leaves you open to SQL injection.  You should use parameterized queries.

Comment: Although in this case it can be prevented by an int.parse... Not recommending it though!

Comment: , @Nick Bray This is not something big, it is work that  I got from school, can you explain what wrong with this connection to the DB code? Thanks you every one!

Comment: Read the link posted by Austin Salonen.  You should use the using statement when you use a dbconnection.

Comment: @RBarryYoung run that code with an article title of `'); DROP TABLE tblArticles; --` and see what happens ;).  Using `string.Format`, under the hood, will just concat the strings together.  It will not sanitize the input strings to ensure they contain entirely literal SQL text with no embedded queries.

Comment: @RobH For the first query, sure, for the second, no, not a chance.

Comment: @RBarryYoung I don't see how you could ever think that it was.  Both of the locations that define the SQL queries use `string.Format` to create the queries.  Do you actually think that using `string.Format` is a safe way to create a query that can't be injected into?  There is no reference to parameters, with respect to the database object, where I could see you possibly thinking that this is using a parameterized query.  The relevant lines are the definitions of `q` and `QueryString`.

Comment: @Servy:  OK, I see, he's using String.Format() substitution.  My eyes  fooled me because explicit parametization in SqlClient can also use the "..{0}.." format, but its perfectly safe there (because its a sql parameter in that case).  Sorry, my bad.

Comment: @Servy Didn't see that query :S

Answer (score 0):

If your code is suddenly exiting from a `try` block unexpectedly, it's catching an exception.

If your catch statement throws away that exception as  `catch { }` does, then you'll never see it.

You should either remove the `try/catch` altogether and let the error bubble up naturally, or you should catch it and do something with it:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
   // However you want to handle things going wrong.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is throwing an exception, most likely because `Request.QueryString["ArticleId"]` has gone out of scope. I'm not sure why this would happen, but it's the most likely explanation. Change `catch {}` to `catch (Exception e) {}` and set a break point there so you can inspect the exception. Assuming this is what's happening, declare a `ArticleId1` outside of the first try and then set it the line after you set `ArticleId` (in the first try).

Comment: If the query string isn't there it will just return `null`.  My guess is he's just getting a null pointer exception when he tries to `ToString` it.